# TYPO3 how to execute code when the extension was activated?

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 version 7.6.16.  how to execute code when the extension was activated ? Do you know how to do it ?

I need to send email with some information (IP, host) after extension was activated.

Comment: Which type of code you want to execute? Can you clear your requirement so reader can understand what you exactly expects. as of now i can say that add your code in the ext_localconf.php might be work.

Comment: I updated my post. Can you help me, please ?

Comment: AFAIK it is a still open feature request: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/4387

Answer (score 4):

I think the signal `afterExtensionInstall` in Extensionmanager should do the trick. Otherwise, you can look for further signals or hooks offered by Extensionmanager.

Example in `ext_localconf.php`

```
$signalSlotDispatcher->connect(
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extensionmanager\Utility\InstallUtility::class,
    'afterExtensionInstall',
    \Vendor\Extension\Hooks\ExtensionInstallation::class,
    'afterInstallation'
);
```

Comment: Thank you! As I understand this hook doing after extension installed, but I need execude code (send email) after extension activated

Comment: I'm glad to have helped to some extent

Comment: @Mikael Despite its name, the afterExtensionInstall hook *actually is executed* on extension activation, not just on the initial extension installation. I recommend to accept his answer, as it is 100% correct and does exactly what you asked for.